# How many flush are required during fixture load?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I'm trying to speed up my build, and I'm asking myself if is it useful to do **LESS** than an em->flush() at the end of every fixture class.

This behaviour is suggested by the Symfony cookbook:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html

...but only 'til 2.2 with the DoctrineFixtureBundle, and I'm on 2.3.

I think a single flush **at the end of ALL fixtures** should be enough, but does Doctrine do it? 
Or I should do it somewhere? 
Is it a correct practice, or it has some hidden complication or error?

Comment: The library/bundle don't do it at the end by themself

Comment: 2.2 is the latest stable version of this bundle. it has it's own versioning, apart from the symfony one.

You basically need one per class

Comment: You can implements OrderedFixtureInterface and set a fixture with the highest order with only the flush call. But in this mode you can't load the fixture selective

Comment: A single `flush()` is sufficient and should be at the end of each fixture class.

Comment: @geoB, that's how it is now, I was wondering about reducing it to a single one in all the fixtures.

Comment: @Matteo you're right, but I've never selectivly reloaded a single fixture since now...

Comment: Because the object manager is instantiated in each class the flush function must occur in each class.  There is no significant performance penalty.  You can always put all of your fixture eggs in a single basket if it's a concern.  Doing so is not really a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, a single flush() will speed up your build. 
You can persist all your objects and after this save them:

```
$manager->persist(object1);

$object2->setParent($object1);
$manager->persist(object2);

$manager->persist(object3);

$manager->flush();
```

Comment: This isn't what I was asking for, that's how I already do my fixtures.

I've edited my questions to explain it better. Thanks anyway.